# Selenium Webdriver - How to execute Perl command with parameters in selenium-Java framework code

Tags: javascript, java, perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on **Selenium** framework with java scripting. I need to use series of Perl commands to execute to inject data into the system before validating the Selenium java scripts.

How to execute Perl scripts inside the Selenium java code ?

Comment: do you want to run perl script using java code?

Comment: Yes Subham, I need to run perl script file to run inside the java code and pass parameter as csv file.

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` function will run your code through java code. Now you are asking for parameter passing. I understand this like there is some variables which you want to pass in this script.

Yes, you can do that using + operator. As similer we concat a string in java using + operator. Similarly pass them. I am posting a sample code for same. Below code will execute your perl script.

Use below code:-

```
    String myvariable = "data";
    Process process;

       try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl C:\\Users\\Shubham\\Desktop\\"+myvariable+"\\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl");
        process.waitFor();
        if (process.exitValue() == 0) {
         System.out.println("Command Successful");
        } else {
         System.out.println("Command Failure");
        }
       } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
       }
      }
    }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi Subham,I am using the command :                                               process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl -w"+ "\\app-ci-test\\src\\test\\resources\\data\\ltplus.pl"+" -d 3 -x "+ "\\app-ci-test\\src\\test\\resources\\data\\xy.csv" +" -t 5 -s 1 -i 1 -r 600");   I am getting Error:                java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "perl": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: is perl is installed in your system.. is it present in your class path .. is perl running fine by executing from terminal(cmd)?

Comment: Thanks Shubham. I installed Perl and Set the path in Env variable. But still it shows the same error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "perl": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified